# jquery initiates automatic call for other js files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see some strange behavior when I check network tab on chrome tools. jQuery is initiating call to other js files of page. These other files are already loaded but jQuery is adding `?_=some_random_number` at the end and calling those files again.

Comment: It sounds like you're using a plugin which is loading other scripts on demand - this is not odd behaviour. It's actually a good thing. Secondly the querystring parameter you see at the end of the URL is to force the browser to download the latest version, not a cached copy.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan . But will this slow down my application? Because I see these files getting called twice in the Network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery does not load other javascript-files by default. You must have another library that loads these resources. And by the way, the `?_={timestamp}` is used to invalidate browser-caching (the url changes every second, so every second a real request is made, not just a browser-cache lookup).

You can try to enforce the ajax-caching mechanism with:

```
$.cache = true;
```

while initializing your code. Thus, the requests will be cached by your browser. But, be aware, that this might tamper with other parts of your code. A better way would be to identify the reason why these extra resources are loaded, and avoid loading.

Comment: Thanks @mazaLe . How can I find which library loads these files? Because I think this can slow down my application as it is unnecessarily loading files again. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Well, you might try to search your HTML-markup for unnessesary `script`-tags. You could try to look over your js-code for additional loading-mechanisms. But in the end, without knowing the specifics of your application, it is hard to tell...

Comment: Perfect! it was because of `script` tag which I was not using. I just commented it and now there are no extra calls. Thank you @maze